# No module named 'PyQt6.QtWidgets'

Tags: pyqt6

I get the above message when I try to use QtWidgets. Has anyone else had this issue and solved it? Just to clarify I have installed PyQt6 using  and there is no issue when I

```
python3 -m pip install PyQt6
```

and there is no issue when I try

```
import PyQt6
```

so the issue is something to do with QtWidgets.

Since downloading I tried

```
app = PyQt6.QtWidgets.QApplication([])
```

and I received the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6.QtWidgets'"

I can't find any information on how to solve this so can anyone help?

I am using macOS 12.5.1 and python 3.9.15.

Comment: Don't import the `PyQt6` main module alone, as it's fundamentally useless: import the namespaces or the submodules: `from PyQt6.QtWidgets import <...>` or `from PyQt6 import QtWidgets`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this import statement instead:

```py
import PyQt6.QtWidgets
```

some packages have kind of 'subpackages'(like `QtWidgets`) you have to import specifically.
I do not know the reasoning behind this, but it is done in bigger packages.

Comment: Sorry, should've said in the question, I've tried that as well and it gives the same issue. Is there anything else I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a "DLL load failed" error, you might want to try reinstalling pyqt6, otherwise try the import statement:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (the modules you need separated by commas)
```

If you are unsure what you want to import, put an asterisk where those parentheses are, like this:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
```

However, this type of import is called a wildcard import and is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what has already been suggested, make sure your interpreter is configured. Check the screenshot below

[Pycharm Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86sQN.png)